# Cannot add AppIcon Images

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I have been desperately trying to add my images into the App Icon set in Xcode but it does not only is allowing me to add in my 960x670 image, then it complains that it does not fit the size dimensions. It does not allow me to place my 120x120 image and others that fit the size dimensions.

By the way, my method of adding in the images is first dragging them into assets.xassets (the general images folder) and then opening the AppIcon set and trying to drag those images into slots in the Appicon Set.

[image]

Why is this happening? Thank you!

Comment: use this site to convert the app icon for all device  https://makeappicon.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

960x670 image is not allowed to set AppIcon, you can read doc following

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html

Comment: I know but it will not let me drag my resized images in, the only one it will let me drag in is 960x720

Comment: opening the AppIcon set, and select the 960x720 image and click delete, then drag your resized images in.

Comment: if the wrong sized image still exist, the error "The app icon set named "AppIcon" did not have any applicable content" will show, so you should make sure your wrong sized image has deleted in set AppIcon.

Comment: I appreciate the help but as it turns out the issue was that I had a JPEG image and it only allows PNG images. I gave you the Check because you tried helping out, I appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have images of those separate specified sizes, and then you need to drag them into the place that is alotted for each size. You can either resize the icon manually or download software from the Mac app store to do it for you.

Comment: I know but it will not let me drag my resized images in, the only one it will let me drag in is 960x720

Comment: I appreciate the help but as it turns out the issue was that I had a JPEG image and it only allows PNG images. I appreciate the help though!